# Changing value on button press using mysql if statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, mysqli

What i am trying to do is change a value on a button press

Ie, Press the button and the value changes from 0 to a 1 one 
     or
    Press the button and the value goes to a 1 from a 0.

and on and on. I am struggling on this part.

```
<?php
include ('db.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect("BLAH CONNECTION");

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM on_offsurvey");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $status = $row["site_status"];

    echo $status;

}

if ($status == 1) {
    $sql = "update on_offsurvey set site_status=0 where id=0)";
} else if ($status == 0)  {
    $sql = "update on_offsurvey set site_status=1 where id=0)";
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
?>
```

That part i am struggling on is the If/If else statement that controls my 0 to 1 or 1 to 0

Any help ?

Comment: Struggling? How are you struggling?

Comment: `mysqli_query($link,...` ?? what is `$link`

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($link ...` What is `$link` ? Did you mean `$result = mysqli_query($conn ...`

Comment: "struggling" isn't an error message or problem statement. We can't fix "struggling", it's not a thing. Please explain more clearly and specifically what your difficulty is.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say you've maybe got an issue because your query potentially returns multiple rows, but because your `if` statement is outside the `while` loop, you only ever consider the last result from the table when running that code. Are you wanting to look at the status of every row?

Comment: P.S. Looking at what I _think_ you're trying to do, I suspect you can solve this purely in SQL, eg. `UPDATE on_offsurvey SET site_status = CASE WHEN site_status = 0 THEN 1 WHEN site_status = 1 THEN 0 END;`. Apologies if the syntax is wrong but you get the general idea. Possibly you need to add `WHERE id=0` as well if you're trying to restrict it to a single row.

Comment: My problem is that the if statement isnt doing what it should. when i refresh the page the value should change from what it currently is in the database to the next from the if statement
So if the current value is 1 then refresh page should then change this to 0
If i refresh again it should change from 0 to 1 thats all its function if for. Potentially change from low to high then high to low... and on.....
The $link is nothing, i have copied from a previous page so please ignore this. It does nothing.

Comment: ADyson, your a legend !!! Perfect. thank you

Comment: @PaulM Glad it helped. I added it as the answer for you to formally accept - thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what I think you're trying to do, I suspect you can solve this purely in SQL, e.g.

```
UPDATE on_offsurvey 
SET site_status = 
  CASE 
    WHEN site_status = 0 THEN 1 
    WHEN site_status = 1 THEN 0 
  END;
```

Apologies if the syntax is wrong but you get the general idea. Possibly you need to add `WHERE id = 0` as well if you're trying to restrict it to a single row.